# Solr core schema changes when indexing csv file

Tags: solr

I am using a standalone solr.

Using solr 7.4.0

- Started solr--> solr start.
- Created solr core--> solr core -c solutionData
- Posted a schema for core solutionData
  `http://localhost:8983/solr/solutionData/schema`

> ```
> {
>   "add-field" : {
>       "name" : "solutiondataid",
>       "type" : "pint"
>   },
>   "add-field" : {
>       "name" : "client",
>       "type" : "string"
>   },
>   "add-field" : {
>       "name" : "goal",
>       "type" : "string"
>   },
>   "add-field" : {
>       "name" : "comment",
>       "type" : "string"
>   },
>   "add-field" : {
>       "name" : "description",
>       "type" : "string"
>   },
>   "add-field" : {
>       "name" : "fmaengid",
>       "type" : "pint"
>   }
> }
> ```

- Now, if I check the schema using:
  `GET http://localhost:8983/solr/solutionData/schema/fields`
  I get following json response:

> ```
> {
>   "responseHeader":{
>     "status":0,
>     "QTime":0},
>   "fields":[{
>       "name":"_root_",
>       "type":"string",
>       "docValues":false,
>       "indexed":true,
>       "stored":false},
>     {
>       "name":"_text_",
>       "type":"text_general",
>       "multiValued":true,
>       "indexed":true,
>       "stored":false},
>     {
>       "name":"_version_",
>       "type":"plong",
>       "indexed":false,
>       "stored":false},
>     {
>       "name":"client",
>       "type":"string"},
>     {
>       "name":"comment",
>       "type":"string"},
>     {
>       "name":"description",
>       "type":"string"},
>     {
>       "name":"fmaengid",
>       "type":"pint"},
>     {
>       "name":"goal",
>       "type":"string"},
>     {
>       "name":"id",
>       "type":"string",
>       "multiValued":false,
>       "indexed":true,
>       "required":true,
>       "stored":true},
>     {
>       "name":"solutiondataid",
>       "type":"pint"}]}
> ```

- Now, I indexed data in a csv file into core. The csv file have same field names as specified in schema.
- Now again I use the schema api as above. I get following json:

> ```
> {
>   "responseHeader":{
>     "status":0,
>     "QTime":0},
>   "fields":[{
>       "name":"_root_",
>       "type":"string",
>       "docValues":false,
>       "indexed":true,
>       "stored":false},
>     {
>       "name":"_solutiondataid",
>       "type":"plongs"},
>     {
>       "name":"_text_",
>       "type":"text_general",
>       "multiValued":true,
>       "indexed":true,
>       "stored":false},
>     {
>       "name":"_version_",
>       "type":"plong",
>       "indexed":false,
>       "stored":false},
>     {
>       "name":"client",
>       "type":"string"},
>     {
>       "name":"comment",
>       "type":"string"},
>     {
>       "name":"description",
>       "type":"string"},
>     {
>       "name":"fmaengid",
>       "type":"pint"},
>     {
>       "name":"goal",
>       "type":"string"},
>     {
>       "name":"id",
>       "type":"string",
>       "multiValued":false,
>       "indexed":true,
>       "required":true,
>       "stored":true},
>     {
>       "name":"solutiondataid",
>       "type":"pint"}]}
> ```

As you all can see , a new field is added to schema i.e. "_solutiondataid"
Can anybody answer what is the issue ?

Comment: My guess is that the field is named `<space>solutiondataid` in your CSV. Confirm that the name is actually what you think it is. You can also disable the update chain that creates fields if they're not known, and see what error message you'll get. If you don't want fields to be created dynamically, it's a good idea to disable that anyway.

Comment: @MatsLindh,  I have checked there is no space in field names.  As per your suggestion, I tried disabling dynamic fields creation.  I deleted the core **solutionData**.  Created it again.  Posted the schema again.  Disabled auto field guessing using command:  bin/solr config -c solutionData -p 8983 -action set-user-property -property update.autoCreateFields -value false  Now again I tried indexing csv file.  Now I am getting below error.  **Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id**  http://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/schemaless-mode.html#disabling-automatic-field-guessing